# Flutter cloned Map updating both values

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an original map called _device, I store this Map in a variable called 'before', then I clone these last ones to a Map called 'after'. Whenever I update 'after' values, the values in 'before' and '_device' are also updated. What's wrong with my code? I have reproduced my code in dartPad and works fine. I'm under master channel 1.26.0-13.pre123.

```
Map<String, dynamic> before = {};
Map<String, dynamic> after = {};
...
before = _device; // _device variable contains Map<String, dynamic>
after = {...before};
...
  if (_storedValue == null) after[_field]['status'] = 'SI';
  if (_storedValue == 'SI') after[_field]['status'] = 'NO';
  if (_storedValue == 'NO') after[_field]['status'] = '(!)';
  if (_storedValue == '(!)') after[_field]['status'] = null;
```

Thanks for any support.

Comment: Dart does not have deep copy functionality so what you are doing is just creating a new `Map` with the same elements as in the `before` map. But the elements are just references to objects so you are really just copying the references which are then pointing to the same objects. You need to implement you own copy functionality where you are creating new objects based on other objects, for this to work.

Comment: Got it, thank you! @julemand101

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> before = {};
Map<String, dynamic> after = {};
//...
before.addAll(_device); // _device variable contains Map<String, dynamic>
after.addAll(before);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is due to how Dart handles object assignment and copying.

In your code, when you assign `before = _device`, you are not creating a new copy of `_device`. Instead, both before and `_device` now reference the same underlying object in memory. So, any changes made to one of them will affect the other.

You can use `Map<String, dynamic> Map.from(Map<dynamic, dynamic> other)` to copy the original `Map`.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> before = {};
Map<String, dynamic> after = {};

before = Map.from(_device);
after = Map.from(before);

if (_storedValue == null) after[_field]['status'] = 'SI';
if (_storedValue == 'SI') after[_field]['status'] = 'NO';
if (_storedValue == 'NO') after[_field]['status'] = '(!)';
if (_storedValue == '(!)') after[_field]['status'] = null;
```